# .Net serialize object to custom JSON (sort of) format

Tags: c#, javascript, json, serialization

I am trying to pass data to a REST service from .Net and the format required by the service is similar to JSON but more like straight JavaScript.

For example:

`{ name:'Test User', first_name:'Test', last_name:'User'}`

Without the key quoted or using full quotes on the string values it doesn't exactly align with the JSON spec and the serializers like JSON.NET don't output in this format. I have tried sending straight up JSON to no avail.

Is there another serializer anyone is aware of that will handle this, or a way to customize the output of something like JSON.NET? I'm basically trying to avoid writing my own.

Comment: Whoever wrote that web service has a sick sense of humor.

Comment: You are right on both counts. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most graceful way to do it, but you could always consider using JSON.NET, serializing your object to a JSON string, then performing string manipulation on the output to get it into the format you desire. I'm sure you could write up a quick method that will take in a JSON string and spit it out in a REST service compatible format. That way you don't exactly have to write your own serializer.

Comment: JSON.NET already has a `QuoteName` property you can set.